# Java Generic Type with wildcard extends class

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I try to use BiConsumer in Java to do an addition, which accepts all Number type.
My code is as follow:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BiConsumer<? extends Number, ? extends Number> addition = (a, b) -> {
            Double sum = a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
        };
        addition.accept(1, 2.3);
    }
}
```

But it will have compiler error as below when I call the accept method in BiConsumer: 
[image]

The accept method has a simple method signature as below:
`void accept(T t, U u);`
I am not familiar with Generic, can anyone explain why we cannot do so?
If it is invalid, why doesn't the compiler indicates when I declare `? extends Number` in the BiConsumer.
And what is the proper why to achieve my goal?

Comment: `BiConsumer<Number, Number> addition` must be the signature. Otherwise it is uncertain what exact Number child class may be passed. Known of `List<? extends Number> numbers` and such.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know what exactly the Number, when you try to accept it. It could be a Float, Double, Integer, etc. of any subclass of Number.
To more understand about _Wildcards_ (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: @JoopEggen then why List<? extends Number> number;
number = new ArrayList<Integer>(); will work?

Comment: @SawanMeshram this should be the same case as List<? extends Number> number;
        number = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
but this works

Comment: @HKIT If one is not sure whether one has a `List<Double>` or `List<Integer>` one cannot `add` any `Number`. And that is the problem here. The addition could actual be assigned a `(BigDecimal a, Short b) ->...` so in general you cannot do an `accept(Double, Integer)`.

Comment: @HKIT Yes, it is actually an upper bound wildcard. List<? extends Number> number; this number list is less restrictive of type Number or any of its subclasses.
Actual fact is that Java doesn’t know what type List really is. If you try to add number to list such as _number.add(100);_ // This will not compile